# Cordova iOS access WWW files

Tags: ios, cordova, url, nsurl, nsbundle

I'm fairly new to iOS development and cordova and I'm a little confused by Xcode and objective-C in terms of how to use an NSUrl or NSBundle to access files. What I want to achieve is to access all of the `.png` files from inside `www/images` from my `app/Classes/MainViewController.m` and programmatically create a new Image View for each one.

My file structure looks like this

```
App Folder > 
           > .xcodeproj file
           > xcode app folder > Classes > MainViewController.m
           > www > images
```

I can handle the instantiation of the image views but I'm confused about how I should be obtaining the images. Is using an NSBundle appropriate in this situation and how can I use an NSURL to navigate from my MainViewController to my images location?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain apps root directory and then add path to your image file:

```
NSString *appFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *imagePath = [appFolderPath stringByAppendingString:@"/www/images/some_image.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

But in general if you are trying to show image from native side, then it is better to put images into Resources folder (using "resource-file" attribute in your plugin.xml) with @2x and @3x postfixes, so iOS will load you appropriate image according to current device.

Plugin.xml example:

```
...
    <platform name="ios">
        ...
        <resource-file src="icons/some_image@2x.png" />
        <resource-file src="icons/some_image@3x.png" />
        ...
    </platform>
...
```

And then in Objective-C:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image"];
```

Comment: I like his 2nd suggestion for plugin development. This assumes "icons/" is in the same directory as plugin.xml. Android will similarly have its own format for using more than one copy of an image based on the resolution of the device, so better not to use the platform-independent www folder.